# Use foreach instead of print_r

Tags: php, foreach

I have a line of code to get attributes :

```
$attributes = $as->getAttributes();
```

When i use print_r

```
$results = print_r($attributes);
```

This is what i get :

```
Array
(
    [http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/subjectkeyidentifier] => Array
        (
            [0] => username
        )

    [http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress] => Array
        (
            [0] => email@mail.com
        )

    [http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/CommonName] => Array
        (
            [0] => User lastname
        )

    [http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn] => Array
        (
            [0] => email@mail.com
        )

    [uid] => Array
        (
            [0] => user
        )

)
```

How can i display those results with a foreach ?

Comment: Do you want the exact same format as a `print_r`, or a different format? If so, why?

Comment: have you tried to use var_export($attributes);?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is it how to write a foreach loop in PHP or do you need the exact formatting as well?

Comment: you can try this : 
   foreach($attributes as $type=>$value){
      echo $type.' : '.$value[0].'<br />;
   }

Comment: Yes, it's because i need to extract a part of the informations and format it differently according to each information.

Comment: from the code samples and the print_r I assume you are using simplexml. Worth to mention if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the informations you can use

```
foreach($attributes as $url=>$info) 
{
   echo $url; //example : http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/subjectkeyidentifier
   foreach($info as $key=>$attr)
   {
      echo $key; //example : 0
      echo $attr; //example : username
   }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me ! many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Per your answers to the comments, you want to be able to format each row differently. Therefore, you could do something like the following:

```
<?php
foreach($attributes as $key => $value){
    echo $key; // the key of the array
    echo $value; // the value of the array row
    echo '<br />'; // if you want a new line
}
```

However, if you want a common format, such as a list, you could use `implode` to do it for you ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)).

```
<?php
echo '<ul><li>'; // Open list and add first open tag
echo implode('</li><li>', $attributes);
echo '</li></ul>'; //Close last item and list element
```

And this would generate an HTML formatted list of the elements, though you certainly could do any delimiter that worked for your project.